How to setup EKS ADOT for sending OpenTelemetry metrics to self managed prometheus?
I have tried to configure ADOT collector using below yaml file
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: adot-collector
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: adot-collector
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: adot-collector
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: adot-collector
          image: public.ecr.aws/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8085
          env:
            - name: AWS_REGION
              value: us-east-1
            - name: AWS_LOG_LEVEL
              value: info
          volumeMounts:
            - name: adot-collector-config
              mountPath: /otel-local-config.yaml
              subPath: adot-collector-config.yaml
      volumes:
        - name: adot-collector-config
          configMap:
            name: adot-collector-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: adot-collector-config
  namespace: monitoring
data:
  adot-collector-config.yaml: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          grpc:
          http:

    processors:
      batch:
      resource:
        attributes:
          - key: service.name
            value: "adot-collector"
            action: upsert

    exporters:
      prometheus:
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8085"

    service:
      pipelines:
        metrics:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch, resource]
          exporters: [prometheus]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: adot-collector
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8085
      targetPort: 8085
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: adot-collector
  type: ClusterIP

But I am getting below error in Prometheus.

I have also opened 8085 in EKS nodes SG. Still it's not working. I also tried to telnet from prometheus port but same error is coming. ADOT pod is also running and logs are not showing any errors. What am I missing? Please help me fix it.
